# Using geometry to prove that $\tan(\alpha)=\frac{\sin(\alpha)}{\cos(\alpha)},\sec(\alpha)=\frac{1}{\cos(\alpha)},...$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles, circles

[image]

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/6sdbz1iahd

Let $\alpha$ be the angle $XOP$. We know that:

$\sin(\alpha)=PA$, and $\cos(\alpha)=PB$

$\tan(\alpha)=PC$, and $\cot(\alpha)=PD$

$\sec(\alpha)=OC$, and $\csc(\alpha)=OD$

---

How can we, using geometry, prove that $PC=\frac{PA}{PB}$, prove that $\frac{1}{PA}=OD$, and so on.

---

I hope you do not consider this as a silly question. I just believe it is (false) to prove these by recalling the trigonometric functions mentioned above.

---

Your help would be appreciated. THANKS!

Comment: Formally, the unit of $PC$ is a length whereas the quotient of two lengths has no dimensions.  So something is fishy here, you missed a line of length 1 somewhere.

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts $OP=1$, which is the radius of the circle.

Answer (score 1):

$\angle CPO=90$ (tangent), $\angle OAP=90$ (AP is altitude)

$\triangle OPC \sim\triangle OAP\ \  \because AAA   $

$\ \ \ \angle CPO=\angle OAP$,

$\ \ \ \angle OCP=(90-\angle COP)=\angle OPA   $

$\ \ \ \angle COP$ is shared

$\therefore \frac{PA}{OA}=\frac{PC}{OP} $

But, $OP=1$ and $OA=PB  $

$\therefore \  PC =\frac{PA}{PB}  $

Comment: Oops. Thank you both for the correction.